# How to Abstract the way this concrete Thread classes are called?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, abstraction

I'm making concrete classes that are subclassed from `Thread` class, so in fact they are threads. Class `A` and `B` in my example.

My class `Foo` gets a `settings` dict, and gets a list of `accounts` (dict items too). For each account then I create a thread `A` that takes two arguments, the whole settings dict, and the account list index that corresponds to each account.

But this example can't use class `B`. Because the call to my Thread Class `A` is hardcoded. How I could abstract `Foo` class to use class `A` or `B` on demand (dynamically) ? As If They were `pluggable actions`...

I'm very new to threads and in python in general. I would accept any other way of archieving the same behaviour. Or if there's a better way, please tell me.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self.accounts = [
            {
                'username': 'DummyUser',
                'password': 'FIXME',
            },
            #...
        ]

    def start_threads(self):
        threads = []
        for i in range(len(self.accounts)):
            post_thread = A(self.settings, self.accounts[i])
            post_thread.setName(self.accounts[i]['username'])
            threads.append(post_thread)

        for t in threads:
            t.start() # Start running the threads!
            t.join()  # Wait for the threads to finish...

class A(Thread):

    def __init__(self, settings, account):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.settings = settings
        self.account = account

    def run(self):
        # Stuff...
        print('%s sleeping for %d seconds...' % (self.getName(), 60))
        time.sleep(60)

class B(Thread):

    def __init__(self, settings, account):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.settings = settings
        self.account = account

    def run(self):
        # Stuff...
        print('%s sleeping for %d seconds...' % (self.getName(), 60))
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = {
        'setting1': 'value1',
        'setting2': 'value2',
        #...
    }

    Foo(settings).start_threads()
```

Comment: But we don't know the condition under which you want to use class `B`.

Comment: I just need to abstract the call to `A`, to be able to call `A` or `B` or `N` Thread classes (they are conceptually the same). Maybe passing the class name to call as argument in `Foo(settings)`. But I'm wondering if there's a more proper way of doing that while using threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, settings, pluggable_action):
       ...
       self.pluggable_action = pluggable_action
    def start_threads(self):
       ....
       post_thread = self.pluggable_action(...)
       ...

 foo = Foo(settings, A) # or B
```

Comment: Very neat ! Works Like a Charm, Thank You!! That's part of python duck typing ? I mean, make the call to a class by using the value that holds ` self.pluggable_action` as the class name.

Comment: No, that is not duck typing. If you want to assign this behavior to one of the cornerstones of Python: everything is an object. A class "constructor" is an object, too. That is why in Python it is called "class object" (that is not an instance of the class, it is the class definition in itself!). It can be passed to a function as a regular argument. It can be called, and when called it creates a new instance of the class. If course it can still be called, after having been passed round between functions/methods. --- Functions are objects, too, and can be passed  just like the class obj here.

Comment: It's an awesome feature, I just Love it.

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you're tring to achieve, is this what you want?

```
thread_class = {'A': A, 'B': B}
post_thread = thread_class['B'](self.settings, self.accounts[i])
```

But this could also be called "hardcoded"...

Comment: In fact, it was.  But It's not object oriented. The accepted answer it's.